# Is there a function that is both exponential or linear at one end and then logarithmic at the other (joining two types of functions generally)

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, mathematical-modeling

This is more a general big picture conceptual question. I observe in life some phenomena display exponential growth. Wealth accumulation or growth of a new business or success as an artist can be included in this bucket. For years, visible signs of success may be slow, and then boom, things exponentiate.

I know some growth is logarithmic. You just can't get past a plateau. There's a kind of natural limit to a level of success. It strikes me that all things that grow exponentially must hit a limit or ceiling. You could also take the case of a foreign species introduced in a new environment in which they thrive. Their growth will be exponential, until it hits the upper limit of the carrying capacity.

Is there a type of function that combines these two concepts? It strikes me that indefinite, infinite exponential functions don't or can't exist in nature, except in rare cases (expansion of universe maybe).

I was wondering if such a thing exists and what the name for such a hybrid function would be, and where I can read up on it more, and how might it be described symbolically. I have never thought of merging or joining two separate types of functions and now I'm really curious.

Comment: Try variants of the [Logistic Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function).

Comment: In real life applications you can encounter functions that are defined as _piecewise functions_ (look it up) because that's the best people can do about them.

Comment: Yes, those are it. Cool to see Verhulst, who developed the logistic function, was aiming at population growth. The piecewise functions look interesting too. My interest was not pure mathematics but modelling nature and it seems in nature things work along intervals (conditions). Wikipedia describes array of functions, which sounds like programming-talk. In nature these functions surely join smoothly together. Modelling nature exactly is probably not easy with pure mathematics. Maybe that's what chaos theory is about. Maybe there's math that describe how functions morph continuously into others

Answer (score 1):

Of interest can be [digamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html) $\psi(x)$.
[image]

On the left side it resembles $-\pi\cot \pi x$ while on the right side it resembles logarithm.